# Reuse template across different recipes

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have a Chef cookbook with many recipes that have the same code, beside other particular things.

```
template 'stack_file' do
    local true
    source File.join(base_dir, 'stack_templates/admin.yml.erb')
    path File.join(base_dir, 'stacks/admin.yml')
    variables(context)
end

template 'settings_file' do
    sensitive true
    local true
    source File.join(base_dir, 'config_templates/settings_admin.yml.erb')
    path File.join(base_dir, 'configs/settings_admin.yml')
    variables(context)
end
```

Is it possible to somehow put this code in a method that I would call with my `source_file`, `destination_file` and `variables`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can write a module and include it in your recipes as you do in plain Ruby.

```
module StackFile
...the code you want to share...
end
```

Then you can use:

```
inlclude StackFile
```

or

```
Chef::Recipe.send(:include, StackFile)
```

or when using `*_if` conditions

```
Chef::Resource.send(:include, StackFile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

1. create new cookbook.
2. don't create recipes in it, but instead create a resource
3. you can define any parameters (inputs like source file, dest file etc like you mentioned)
4. add your templates to the new cookbook.
5. in your other cookbooks, create dependency to the previously created cookbook. This will enable you to call the resource you created there (remember that when you call resource from another cookbook and it is creating templates, it will try to take the template file from the current cookbook and not the one where the resource is defined. That is why you need to specify cookbook name when creating template (in the shared cookbook's resource) - see cookbook attribute of https://docs.chef.io/resource_template.html)
6. Repeat for any number of cookbooks.